RTSP to HLS conversion with error on some devices
I'm trying to convert, on a node server, RTSP IP camera devices to HLS to run livestreams on the web. The following code works well for some RTSP devices, but for others I encounter problems.
   function startLive(rtspUrl, outputDir, id_local, id_camera) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const processKey = `${id_local}_${id_camera}`;
            if (ffmpegProcesses[processKey]) {
                return reject(new Error('Conversão já está em andamento para esta câmera'));
            }
        
            const process = ffmpeg(rtspUrl)
                .inputOptions([
                    '-rtsp_transport', 'tcp',
                    '-fflags', 'nobuffer',
                    '-max_delay', '1000000',
                    '-analyzeduration', '1000000',
                    '-probesize', '1000000',
                    '-flush_packets', '1',
                    '-avioflags', 'direct'
                ])
                .outputOptions([
                    '-c:v', 'libx264',
                    '-preset', 'ultrafast',
                    '-tune', 'zerolatency',
                    '-c:a', 'aac',
                    '-hls_time', '10',
                    '-hls_flags', 'delete_segments',
                    '-hls_list_size', '5',
                    '-hls_wrap', '5',
                    '-strict', '-2'
                ])
                .output(path.join(outputDir, 'stream.m3u8'))
                .on('start', (commandLine) => {
                    console.log('Spawned FFmpeg with command: ' + commandLine);
                })
                .on('stderr', (stderrLine) => {
                    console.log('FFmpeg stderr: ' + stderrLine);
                })
                .on('end', () => {
                    console.log('Conversão concluída');
                    delete ffmpegProcesses[processKey]; 
                    resolve();
                })
                .on('error', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                    console.error('Erro na conversão', err);
                    console.error('FFmpeg stdout:', stdout);
                    console.error('FFmpeg stderr:', stderr);
                    delete ffmpegProcesses[processKey]; 
                    reject(err);
                })
                .run();
    
            ffmpegProcesses[processKey] = process; 
        });
    }

When the conversion succeeds, it continues indefinitely with the logs:
FFmpeg stderr: frame=   61 fps= 48 q=13.0 size=N/A time=00:00:02.03 bitrate=N/A dup=60 drop=0 speed= 1.6x    
FFmpeg stderr: frame=   75 fps= 42 q=17.0 size=N/A time=00:00:02.52 bitrate=N/A dup=62 drop=0 speed=1.41x    
FFmpeg stderr: frame=   91 fps= 39 q=16.0 size=N/A time=00:00:03.04 bitrate=N/A dup=65 drop=0 speed=1.31x    
FFmpeg stderr: frame=  108 fps= 38 q=15.0 size=N/A time=00:00:03.60 bitrate=N/A dup=68 drop=0 speed=1.27x    
FFmpeg stderr: frame=  121 fps= 36 q=24.0 size=N/A time=00:00:04.03 bitrate=N/A dup=70 drop=0 speed=1.21x    
FFmpeg stderr: frame=  138 fps= 36 q=16.0 size=N/A time=00:00:04.60 bitrate=N/A dup=73 drop=0 speed= 1.2x    
FFmpeg stderr: frame=  152 fps= 35 q=17.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.08 bitrate=N/A dup=75 drop=0 speed=1.17x    
FFmpeg stderr: frame=  168 fps= 35 q=16.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.60 bitrate=N/A dup=78 drop=0 speed=1.15x    
FFmpeg stderr: frame=  183 fps= 34 q=21.0 size=N/A time=00:00:06.11 bitrate=N/A dup=80 drop=0 speed=1.13x    
FFmpeg stderr: frame=  198 fps= 34 q=16.0 size=N/A time=00:00:06.60 bitrate=N/A dup=83 drop=0 speed=1.12x    
FFmpeg stderr: frame=  215 fps= 33 q=16.0 size=N/A time=00:00:07.16 bitrate=N/A dup=86 drop=0 speed=1.11x    
FFmpeg stderr: frame=  230 fps= 33 q=16.0 size=N/A time=00:00:07.66 bitrate=N/A dup=88 drop=0 speed= 1.1x    
FFmpeg stderr: frame=  246 fps= 33 q=19.0 size=N/A time=00:00:08.20 bitrate=N/A dup=91 drop=0 speed= 1.1x    

And with the segments saved in the folder configured as output. But for certain devices, after creating the stream.m3u8 file and saving the first segment, the conversion is considered finished and falls into .on('end') . The error log is as follows:
FFmpeg stderr: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.12 bitrate=N/A speed=2.08x    
FFmpeg stderr: [hls @ 0x55e00dfc4380] Opening 'my_path/stream0.ts' for writing
FFmpeg stderr: [hls @ 0x55e00dfc4380] Opening 'my_path/stream.m3u8.tmp' for writing
FFmpeg stderr: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:01.37 bitrate=N/A speed= 2.5x    
FFmpeg stderr: video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
FFmpeg stderr: [aac @ 0x55e00dfff840] Qavg: 65536.000
FFmpeg stderr: 
Conversão concluída

The muxing overhead: unknown only appears when the error occurs and the conversion is complete.
I've already tried changing the video and audio encoders, as well as the various input and output parameters of the conversion. I also tried updating ffmpeg (it's already on the latest version, using fluent-ffmpeg, "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.3",)
I've tried changing the TCP protocol to UDP, but, although the error changed, the output is never created
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] RTP: missed 6 packets
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] max delay reached. need to consume packet
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] RTP: missed 6 packets
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] max delay reached. need to consume packet
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] RTP: missed 6 packets
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] max delay reached. need to consume packet
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] RTP: missed 9 packets
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] max delay reached. need to consume packet
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] RTP: missed 6 packets
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] max delay reached. need to consume packet
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] RTP: missed 6 packets
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] max delay reached. need to consume packet
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] RTP: missed 6 packets
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] max delay reached. need to consume packet
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] RTP: missed 6 packets
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] max delay reached. need to consume packet
FFmpeg stderr: [rtsp @ 0x55e43eeae700] RTP: missed 8 packets


Thanks

What are the devices?
